# Should I upgrade - jaunty 9.0.4 server - as it's not LTS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, ubuntu, upgrade

On my production server this is the output of `lsb_release -a`

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 9.04
Release:    9.04
Codename:   jaunty
```

Should I update and move to a LTS version of Ubuntu now? I'm running a Ruby On Rails application and I use things like image magic etc ok at the moment with no big issues that I've noticed.

Eg. Is there any reason why running Rails 3x with Mysql on Ubuntu Jaunty 9.04 could cause problems currently with the latest versions of Rails + Ruby + And Linux Stuff if I continue to update my rails / ruby and associated gems without updating my OS and associated packages?

I will possibly be migrating servers within a year and at that point I would have the opportunity (requirement) to install any version of Ubuntu I desired. Then again, I could stay on this OS for the foreseeable future if you were all to say "don't bother.."

Note: I'm actually a Slicehost customer and there is no 'easy' upgrade method, I'd have to get another slice, pay for it for a month, copy my data and on and on. If I then did decide to leave Slicehost then I would be going through this process all over again. In that case, with the possibility of downtime on a live production site, is it worth it?

Comment: Just to respond to your edit, "Don't bother" is probably not a good idea. They don't even let you download Jaunty anymore. If you migrate servers, go with Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS. And find an infastructure that lets you update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were one or two versions behind, it might be OK, but considering how important security is, you must ALWAYS update at least the packages, and Jaunty no longer has package support (10.10 lost it about a month ago). You **need** to upgrade your server. Ubuntu is currently at version 12.04, which is 5 versions ahead of you. Prepare to spend a lot of time upgrading and for some major downtime, but it's better then the kind of downtime that old software and security holes can create. Linux can only be secure if you update it -- the famous security somes from the fast patching, so you'd better take the patches.

If I were you, I'd say pay once and go to Ubuntu 12.04 Server LTS. It will be supported for a while yet. But if you have infrastructure that disallows upgrading, I suggest you change hosts. A host where you can't upgrade or where they don't upgrade for you is a lousy host.

Comment: Thanks for giving it to me straight.

Comment: @LpLrich: Sure. I may have said it a little to straight, but glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should. It's always better to keep all services up-to-date especially if it's a server. However, you should probably try the migration on a development server before applying it to a production server.

Comment: Thanks for the response - I've added a little more info to my question. Do you still think that it is generally better to go through the upgrade process in this context? Of course, had you said "Yes straight away there is an issue with Ruby x.x.x and Jaunty 9.04" then I'd have had to have considered it urgently.

Comment: @LpLrich: Even though I can't give you an exact conflict, 5 distribution updates old is like saying that you want to run a server on Windows XP (although there updates cost more). If this is a production server, especially if it has important data (business data, credit cards, e-finance stuff), people will not be happy if that isen't secure. And sensitive data even extends to stuff like e-mails and usernames, so be careful.

Comment: There has been enormous security issues in Ruby, as said above you **need** to upgrade all your services, however you should (must?) try an upgrade from a dev server first. And, in the future try to do updates frequently to never be again in this delicate situation. Good Luck!

Comment: In fact, if you follow some basic safety rules, you should not consider this server as trustworthy.

Comment: @torr: Couldn't have put it better. Updates are a necessity. Without them is like asking me to store my personal information on Windows 95.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments, its all very much appreciated. I've learned my lesson now and I will always keep on top of this side of things from now on.